# how to use parser data from one Activity to Another data in android

Tags: java, android

how to use parser data from one Activity to Another data in android, Please help anyone help parser data from one activity to another actibity.

```
public class ClassA extends BaseActivity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.book_now_screen);

    }

    @Parcel
    public static class BookTicketData {

        @SerializedName("internetFee")
        public String mInternetFee;

    }
}


ClassB

public class ClassB extends BaseActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.book_now_screen_confirm); 

        private ClassA.BookTicketData  mCardData;   
        TextView bsc_internetcharges_price = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.internetcharges_price);
        bsc_internetcharges_price.setText(mCardData.mInternetFee);   
    }
}
```

Error shows:

```
Unable to start activity ComponentInfo
```

Comment: I'm not sure I follow. What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: What is the problem , and where is the activity ComponentInfo you have showed only two activity i.e., ClassA and  ClassB , also post the error from LogCat

Comment: @L-X  SerizeName contain of key i classA but I have to set this key valur to ClassB Textview.

Comment: Ok , I can see you are using annotation , can you try this thing  public String mInternetFee="internetFee"; instead of using @SerializedName(...)